# Switch-Case statement seems to freeze my loops

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

Here are a few loops from my program I'm working on. The program seems to stop advancing after `printf("TEST2");`. Everything checks out at a glance. Is there something I'm missing?

*I'm expecting the loop to repeat after setting the values in the switch-statement. I know it's getting through it at least once.*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char *names[] = { "Denise", "Inja", "Jane", "Karen", "Maggie", "Margaret", "MJ", "Queen", "Sherri", NULL }; //ptr for names, 9 nurses
const char days[5][10] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
int randomNurse();
#define total_nurses 9 //number of nurses on staff
#define days_in_week 5 //number of work days in a week


int main() {

srand(time(NULL));
int day, pos, candidate, i, j;
int slackers[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }; //array that holds the selections for who isn't working
char **name_ptr = names;
/*0 = Denise, 1 = Inja, 2 = Jane, 3 = Karen, 4 = Maggie, 5 = Margaret, 6 = MJ, 7 = Queen, 8 = Sherri*/
int avail_nurses[total_nurses] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }; //holds the status of each nurse, 0 = unavailable, 1 = available

/*prints names */
int temp_counter = 1; //counter
while (*name_ptr) {
    printf("%i) %s\n", temp_counter, *name_ptr);
    name_ptr++;
    temp_counter++;
}

/*this assumes that no more than FOUR nurses will be away on any given week*/
printf("\nEnter numbers that correspond to the nurses who won't be available for the week.\nType up to four numbers, each separated by a space.\n");
printf("When you are done, press \"Enter\".\n");
printf("If less than four nurses will be on leave, type a \"0\" in place of a selection.\n");
printf("Example: 1 2 5 0\n\n\n");

/*week selection of unavailable nurses*/
    do {
        printf("Who won't be here?  ");
    } while (scanf("%i %i %i %i", &slackers[0], &slackers[1], &slackers[2], &slackers[3]) != 4);

/*checks the selections made, and sets the available nurses to the correct value, zero if they are slacking||vacationing*/
for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
    int slacker = slackers[n];
    if (slacker >= 1 && slacker <= 9)
        avail_nurses[slacker] = -1;
}


/*-----WEEKLY_ASSIGNMENT-----*/
int pos_per_day[days_in_week] = { 5, 9, 9, 8, 5 }; //number of nurses needed each day

int selection[days_in_week][total_nurses]; //the selected nurses per day 

for (i = 0; i < days_in_week; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < total_nurses; j++) {
        selection[i][j] = -1; //initialize to -1 which means no nurse is selected
    }
}

//fill all the days of week 
for (day = 0; day < days_in_week; day++) {
    for (pos = 0; pos < pos_per_day[day]; pos++) { //for every position needed that day
        do {
            candidate = randomNurse();
        } while (!avail_nurses[candidate]); //looks for available nurses (phrasing)

        avail_nurses[candidate] = 0;  //change nurses status to not available
        selection[day][pos] = candidate;  //fill the output array with appropriate nurse
    }
    for (i = 0; i < total_nurses; i++) {
        avail_nurses[i] = 1; //initialize the nurses status for next day use
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) { //make sure we shame the slackers...
        int slacker = slackers[n];
        if (slacker >= 1 && slacker <= 9)
            avail_nurses[slacker] = -1;
    }
}

/*-----PRINTS SCHEDULE FOR WEEK-----*/
for (i = 0; i < days_in_week; i++) {
    printf("%-10s: ", days[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < total_nurses; j++) {
        if (selection[i][j] != -1)
            printf("%-10s ", names[selection[i][j]]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}

/*function to generate random nurse*/
int randomNurse() {

return rand() % 9; //random number 0-8, to pick nurse
}
```

Comment: Use `break` instead of `continue` to begin with. Also, where is the definition of `AVAIL_NURSES`??? Add the relevant piece of code please. BTW, it looks like you can simply check if `slackers[n]` is between 1 and 9, and then use `AVAIL_NURSES[slackers[n]-1] = 0` instead of the entire `switch` statement.

Comment: The only code that has the potential to be in an infinite loop is the `do-while` block. Add a `printf` in that block to see if that is the problem.

Comment: Darn you R Sahu!!! UI was just about to say that!

Comment: Why, oh why, do you use the `for-switch` construct? Just replace your entire `switch` statement with `int slacker = slackers[n]; if (slacker >= 1 && slacker <= 9]) AVAIL_NURSES[slacker] = 0;`

Comment: @barakmanos I added all the code. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @SingleStepper, next time let me know when you are about to add a comment. I'll try not to add a comment before you do :) :)

Comment: There is this "Debug" menu in Visual Studio, have you tried to look what's inside?

Answer (score 2):

You have Undefined Behaviour. The second value in `pos_per_day` is 9, which is outside the bounds of the `select` array. Subtracting one from each value in that array may be enough to fix it.

Other bad problems:

- you need to validate the input data after `scanf`.
- the switch statement is completely unnecessary. Replace it by a calculation.
- don't use UPPER CASE for variables. By convention, that's only for defined constants.
- don't hard code numbers like 5 and 9. Replace them by DEFINED CONSTANTS.

You **must** learn how to debug simple programs like this, using the debugger available to you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the out of bounds. This program runs if I leave out the `switch-case` statement inside that `for-loop`. Changing the size of the arrays didn't seem to help.

I fixed all my other issues and updated the code. I would appreciate further critique.

Comment: The code is now different, but now slacker can be 9 and avail_nurses[9] is out of bounds. This is simple debugging, which does not make for good questions on this site. You really do need to learn to do this yourself.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by it being out of bounds.

I understand I need to learn it myself, but how am I supposed to learn something I don't understand already?

Comment: Write code, read code, do tutorials, search the web, read a book, experiment, think, the usual way we learn things. Takes about 10 years to be really good at this stuff. No shortcuts.